# Error ArrayList

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LINQArrayListTips05
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
            lista.AddRange(new object[] { "hola", 5, 6.7, false, 4, 2, "saludos", 3.5, 3 });

            var enteros = lista.OfType<int>();

            foreach (int n in enteros)
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");

            ArrayList estudiantes = new ArrayList();

            {
                new CEstudiante("Jhon", "A203", "Telemática", 3.6),
                new CEstudiante("Ana", "B304", "Informática", 4.2),
                new CEstudiante("Pedro", "C405", "Psicología", 2.6),
                new CEstudiante("Erick", "D506", "Escritura", 4.9),
                new CEstudiante("Jaime", "E607", "Ingles", 1.6),
                new CEstudiante("Juan", "F708", "Humanidades", 3.8)
            };

            var estL = estudiantes.OfType<CEstudiante>();

            var reprobados = from e in estL
                             where e.Promedio <= 3.0
                             select e;

            Console.WriteLine("Reprobados");
            foreach (CEstudiante r in reprobados)
                Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.WriteLine("Presione un tecla para continuar");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error CS1002  Se esperaba ;

Al poner el `;` donde el compilador lo pide, el programa no funciona como debería. ¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto?

Comment: Define "como debería"... ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado?

Comment: Si eliminas el punto y como que tienes al final de `estudiantes = new ArrayList();`

Comment: Y ademas, en que lugar te solicita el punto y coma?

Comment: @Kiko_L lo ha sugerido, pero quiero poner énfasis en ello. No useis `ArrayList`, no se ha suprimido de .net por retrocompatibilidad, pero es obsoleto. Se debe usar Siempre `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes reemplazar esta parte de codigo:

```
ArrayList estudiantes = new ArrayList()
{
    new CEstudiante("Jhon", "A203", "Telemática", 3.6),
    new CEstudiante("Ana", "B304", "Informática", 4.2),
    new CEstudiante("Pedro", "C405", "Psicología", 2.6),
    new CEstudiante("Erick", "D506", "Escritura", 4.9),
    new CEstudiante("Jaime", "E607", "Ingles", 1.6),
    new CEstudiante("Juan", "F708", "Humanidades", 3.8)
};
```

tienes el punto y coma donde no es

Comment: Seria bueno que explicaras por que el error de compilacion `CS1002` referente al punto y coma, y porque asi se resuelve.

Answer (score 3):

Varias cosas:

- Como te comentan, lo primero es quitar el `;` de esta línea `ArrayList estudiantes = new ArrayList();`

  ```
     ArrayList estudiantes = new ArrayList(){
          new CEstudiante("Jhon", "A203", "Telemática", 3.6),
          new CEstudiante("Ana", "B304", "Informática", 4.2),
          new CEstudiante("Pedro", "C405", "Psicología", 2.6),
          new CEstudiante("Erick", "D506", "Escritura", 4.9),
          new CEstudiante("Jaime", "E607", "Ingles", 1.6),
          new CEstudiante("Juan", "F708", "Humanidades", 3.8)
      };
  ```

Con las llaves `{}` estás inicializando el `ArrayList` con los valores indicados. Si le añades un `;` antes lo que estás haciendo es instanciar un `ArrayList` vacío y luego ejecutar una orden incorrect ({new CEstudiante...})

- En el `foreach` final estás imprimiendo el objeto entero `r`, cuando (entiendo) que lo que querrías es imprimir sus propiedades:

  `Console.WriteLine(r.Promedio); //no sé cómo se llaman el resto de propiedades de la clase CEstudiante`
- Y por último, ¿por qué haces esto?

  `var estL = estudiantes.OfType<CEstudiante>();`

Sería más sencillo (y correcto) directamente crear un `List` de `CEstudiante` así:

```
       List<CEstudiante> estudiantes = new List<CEstudiante>(){
            new CEstudiante("Jhon", "A203", "Telemática", 3.6),
            new CEstudiante("Ana", "B304", "Informática", 4.2),
            new CEstudiante("Pedro", "C405", "Psicología", 2.6),
            new CEstudiante("Erick", "D506", "Escritura", 4.9),
            new CEstudiante("Jaime", "E607", "Ingles", 1.6),
            new CEstudiante("Juan", "F708", "Humanidades", 3.8)
        };
```

**Edito**
Por petición de @Orlando-de-la-rosa añado [este](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1002) enlace a como referencia al error CS1002:

> El compilador detectó que falta un punto y coma. Se requiere un punto y coma al final de cada una de las instrucciones de C#. Una instrucción puede abarcar más de una línea.

Tal y como dice @Pikoh en su comentario:

> No useis ArrayList, no se ha suprimido de .net por
>   retrocompatibilidad, pero es obsoleto. Se debe usar Siempre `List<T>`

Lo dejo aquí para que sea más visible